# In SQL Server how to have a paymentdate greater than the month and year ignoring the day part?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, date

In Oracle:

```
select 
    name, 
    case 
       when PaymentDate is not null 
            and PaymentDate <= to_date('202001','yyyyMM')
          then 'Paid'  
          else NotPaid
where 
    empId  in(%s)) ;
```

I need the SQL Server equivalent of the above query. I just need to check the month and year part of the date with paymentdate's month and year. Please advice.

Need the `to_date('202001','yyyyMM')` equivalent in SQL Server.

Comment: What does this mean? Is this testing for a paymentdate starting in February to the end of time? If so `(DatePart(year, PaymentDate)*100) + DatePart(month, PaymentDate) <= 202001` would be an option.

Comment: try_cast('202001' + '01' as date)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `to_date('202001','yyyyMM')` produces a `date` value that represents January 1st, 2020.

You can get the same result in SQL Server with an expression such as `cast('2020-01-01' as date)` or `cast('20200101' as date)`.

If your input (`'202001'`) is coming from outside the query and you cannot modify its value, you can concatenate `'01'` at the end: `cast(concat(@myparam, '01') as date)`.

---

The rest of your query has syntax errors:

- missing quotes around `'Not Paid'`
- missing `end` keyword at the end of the `case` expression
- missing `from` clause
- superfluous closing parenthese at the end of the query

It is also worth noting that the condition in the `case` expression can be simplified by removing the superfluous `is not null` predicate:

```
select 
    name, 
    case when PaymentDate <= cast('2020-01-01' as date)
        then 'Paid'  
        else NotPaid
    end
from mytable
where empId in (%s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the beginning of the month. You can apply it to both PaymentDate and Date, then do the comparison

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, PaymentDate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle always return 1st day of the month when you convert to_date. So in this case it is 1st Jan 2020.

Generally SQL server have default date format at YYYY-MM-DD. If you want to match date as per SQL server then you need to manipulate the input string to as per date format

SELECT CAST((LEFT('202001',4) + '-' + RIGHT('202001',2) + '-01') as Date)

As per your query

select 
    name, 
    case 
       when PaymentDate is not null 
            and PaymentDate <= CAST((LEFT('202001',4) + '-' + RIGHT('202001',2) + '-01') as Date)
          then 'Paid'
          else 'NotPaid'
where 
    empId  in(%s)) ;

Answer (score 0):

`select * from payment_table where month(payment_date) > 2 and year(payment_date) >= 2020;`